# How to get price with webhook Trading View(pine script)?

Tags: pine-script

My code:

```
alert('{"content": "BTC SHORT {{close}}"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

I got this:

```
BTC SHORT {{close}}
```

But i need something like this:

```
BTC SHORT 27455.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `alert()` function, you can use the `str.tostring()` function to convert a number into a string.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

c = str.tostring(math.round(close, 1))

alert('{"content": "BTC SHORT ' + c + '"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```